# Jquery and on function?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am a newbie to jquery.
I have a checkbox

```
<label id="2p">
    <input type="radio" name="due" class="due"  value="2p" checked="yes" />
    <span class="testoCheckbox">2p</span>
</label>
```

dynamically appended to a div. Being appended after load, change or click event won't be fired. I understood that the solution to catch the click on the checkbox must be in the "on" function but i can't get the right syntax for it. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `on()` to check for events on elements added dynamically this way:

```
$(document).on('change', '.due', function(event){

    // do your stuff

});
```

Whenever a `change` event is fired inside the document, if it matches `.due` selector, callback is fired.

You may want to narrow your selection for better performance:

```
$('#someDiv').on('change', '.due', function(event){

    // do your stuff

});
```

If you want to target *all* the checkboxes contained in `#someDiv`:

```
$('#someDiv').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(event){

    // do your stuff

});
```

Comment: the first code you provided seemed the Shangri La, but there's still a problem. It works for the checkbox i asked for, but i have a second checkbox group (precisely they are two radio group, not checkbox, sorry for the imprecision) <label id="2p_1">
    <input type="radio" name="tre" class="tre"  value="2p_1" checked="yes" />
    <span class="testoCheckbox">2p-1</span>
</label> and the code works for the "due group" but not for "tre"group ^^'

Comment: Of course, because you are selecting just `.due` elements - if you want to select more elements, give either them a common class [e.g. "checkGroup"], or stick to all checkboxes in a common ancestor element [see my edit].

Comment: i forgot to say i added a $(document).on('click', '.tre', function(event){alert("yea");}); thinking to replicate the mechanism cause i wanted to distinguish the fire of the event for "due" from the firing for "tre" to implement two different behaviour. There's still something i cannot understand. I'll try to wrap the two in two divs

Comment: If you want to implement different behaviors, provide different listeners. If behaviors are slightly different, you may want to check for element's class inside a common listener, i.e. inside callback: `if( $(this).hasClass('tre') ) { doStuff }`, and so.

Comment: an then i forgot to add class="tre" to the second group of checkboxes :p Shame on me! Replicating your code in the way i said in the last edit all worked! And learned something new! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll try the common listener too. It's interesting. Can i ask you why you talked about better performance in using the second version of your code, wrapping all in a common div?

Comment: Narrowing action range is alway better, because an element will always be a proper subset of whole DOM => less elements to listen to about events. Non to mention that if you want to unbind the listener, you just drop it off from `#someDiv`, and not from whole `document` [in case you still need to listen to `change` events].

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17202/discussion-between-moonwave99-and-elisabetta-falivene)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$('body').on('click', '.due', function() {
  // do something here
});
```

see: [jQuery `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: The way you write it, is why live was originally deprecated. Instead of body, use the direct ancestor element.

Comment: @Christoph Couldn't disagree lesser!! `body` is also a common ancestor. I feel its fine using it this way.

Comment: I downvoted, because you are promoting bad practice. It makes no sense to bind the event to body while you can bind it to the parent div or even `"#2p"`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can say it's bad practice. It's possible (though not in this case) for elements in a given document to only share the `body` element. In that case, why not use `body`? This is legitimate, valid code. Maybe not the best choice, but hardly a bad answer

Comment: Ah! the asker hasn't posted the entire code. You can't imagine any better parent element.

Comment: just a stupid question: a label can the considered an ancestor as it was a div? I mean, if you're talking about a div containing another i would have understood who was the ancestor of another, but in this case it is a label wrapping an input...

Comment: @ElisabettaFalivene ya I believe you're right! a div is more of an ancestor instead of a label which just appears to be wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

as far as I know you can dynamicly append checkbvox with `onclick=""` event and it should work properly. If you want to do it with jQuery you should define id (say "myCheckbox") and do

```
$('#myCheckbox').click(function(){
  //your code here.
});
```

Or if you want to append the same action for all the checkboxes, use different selector ie: `.due`
By the way, `.click(handler)` is just a shortcut to `.on("click", handler)` accourding to docs: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score -2):

As you load the checkbox dynamicly, jQuery can't bind the event on it on pageload, with .live (replaced by .on in >= jQuery 1.7) you can achieve the following:

"Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future."

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer:

```
$(body).on("click", ".due", function() {
  // Handler
});
```

Comment: The [`.live()` method is deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com). Use `.on()` instead (or `.delegate()` if you're using jQuery below 1.7). The OP even asks for the `.on()` method!

Comment: Changed my answer to use the .on() instead of .live()

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. You need to delegate the event handler higher up the DOM tree.

Comment: At least, quote the `body` to make it a valid selector.